# ReactJS Redux Provider won't take the store

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, provider

I am trying to update my redux store from "createStore" to "configureStore" because of the depreciation of "createStore".
I'm on ReactJS 17 with TypeScript, and Redux / Redux dependencies versions are :

```json
"redux": "^4.2.0",
"redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
"redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.3",
```

Problem is, after configured the store, the Provider on my index.tsx, won't take the store. I've got this error :

`Cannot assign type '(preloadedState?: PreloadedState<RootState>) => EnhancedStore<CombinedState<{ orders: any; auth: {}; errors: {}; }>, any, MiddlewareArray<[ThunkMiddleware<CombinedState<{ orders: any; auth: {}; errors: {}; }>, AnyAction, undefined>]>>' to type 'Store<any, AnyAction>'.ts(2322`

I checked the Redux documentation, checked StackOverflow & Google, but I can't find any solution.

Here are my pages :

### store.tsx

```
import { configureStore, PreloadedState } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducer/rootReducer"

export const store = (preloadedState?: PreloadedState<RootState>) => {
    return configureStore({
      reducer: rootReducer,
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware(),
      preloadedState
      
    })
}

export default store;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof store>;
export type AppDispatch = AppStore['dispatch'];
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
```

### index.tsx

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { consultFilters } from './actions/Actions';
import { store } from './store';



store.dispatch(consultFilters());

ReactDOM.render(
    (<Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>)
  ,
  document.getElementById('root') || document.createElement('div')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
export const store = (preloadedState?: PreloadedState<RootState>) => {
    return configureStore({
      reducer: rootReducer,
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware(),
      preloadedState
      
    })
}
```

This is not a Redux store - it's a function that creates a Redux store.

Either just do

```js
export const store = configureStore({
      reducer: rootReducer,
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware(),
    }
```

or if you need that callback

```js
export const makeStore = (preloadedState?: PreloadedState<RootState>) => {
    return configureStore({
      reducer: rootReducer,
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware(),
      preloadedState
    })
}

export const store = makeStore()
```

By the way, if you really are just doing

```
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware(),
```

you can drop that whole line. The default middleware is, as the name implies, the default.

Also, please note that the deprecation of `createStor` is just an indicator that your whole code base might be following a style of Redux that is outdated since 2019 and is about 4 times the code of modern Redux (and a lot more error-prone).
Please read https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today

Comment: Thanks!!! That made the thing. You are the man!! I passed by those informations, and did not understood that difference. Thanks a lot, know that's better in my mind !!